# Merge three lines into one

Tags: awk, sed, merge

I have problem. At first I am converting xlsm to tsv. One column has \n delimited strings and if I use xlsx2csv tool, I received from this one row a three rows.

F.E.:
XLSM file:

```
> 2 LO rofl string_A 
> 1 HI lol "string| 
>           string_2|
>           string_3"
```

In .TSV file

```
> 2 LO rofl string_A   
> 1 HI lol "string|   
> string_2|  
> string_3"
```

And I would like to get automatically for all rows if column $1 starts by string2 or string3 result like:

```
 > 2 LO rofl string_A 
 > 1 HI lol "string|string2|string3"
```

Could you help me please, the best by awk or sed please.
Thank you..

Comment: I guess you meant three lines not files?

Comment: Right.I meant three lines :-(

Comment: I am thinking about this problem... I think I could find a last column... I column ends with "|" add row under and again and again. I am trying o write a script, but does not work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's REALLY not clear what you are asking for help with - xlsm format files, whatever they are, or xlsx2csv, whatever that is (everyone and their grandma has a tool by that name and I doubt if you're calling mine!), or tsv files that don't seem to contain any tabs, or something else. Nor is it obvious from your sunny-day input example what rainy-day situations you might have (e.g. embedded `"`s) and whether or not every line of your files really starts with `>` or if you just don't know how to format your example.

So, given all of that, try this using GNU awk for multi-char RS and RT:

```
awk -v RS='"[^"]*\n[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\s*\n\s*/,"",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
```

and good luck!

For example:

```
$ cat file
2 LO rofl string_A
1 HI lol "string|
          string_2|
          string_3"

$ awk -v RS='"[^"]*\n[^"]*"' '{gsub(/\s*\n\s*/,"",RT); ORS=RT} 1' file
2 LO rofl string_A
1 HI lol "string|string_2|string_3"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, problem solved and I apologize for the confusing answer. Best fedulka